# Почему у меня не выставляет счет киви?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, qiwi

{'serviceName': 'payin-invoicing-api', 'errorCode': 'http.message.conversion.failed', 'description': 'Неверный запрос', 'userMessage': 'Неверный запрос', 'dateTime': '2022-08-06T23:15:51.869+03:00'}

В чем проблема?

```
    def create_invoice(self,
                       bill_id: str,
                       amount: float,
                       expiration_date_time: str,
                       currency: str = 'RUB',
                       comment: str = '',
                       theme_code: str = ''):
        return requests.put(f'https://api.qiwi.com/partner/bill/v1/bills/{bill_id}',
                            params={
                                'amount': {
                                    'value': amount,
                                    'currency': currency
                                },
                                'comment': comment,
                                'expirationDateTime': expiration_date_time,
                                'customFields': {
                                    'themeCode': theme_code
                                }
                            },
                            headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer ТОКЕН',
                                     'Accept': 'application/json',  'content-type': 'application/json'}).json()


        qiwi_create_invoice = Qiwi.create_invoice(random_num, 1.00, datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M') + "+03:00", 'RUB', '', '')
```

Comment: random_num = random.randint(321312, 52398580295802)

Comment: Qiwi - это класс где лежит функция создания платежа